# Magento 1.9.4 Third party model override doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, override-model

I've been trying for days now to get a rewritten model to function. but it doesn't work, I'm puzzled because all seems to be correct.

___Here's my config file : etek/advancednewslettercoupon/etc/config.xml

```
    <global>
          <models>
            <advancednewslettercoupon>
                <class>Etek_AdvancedNewsletterCoupon_Model</class>
            </advancednewslettercoupon>
            <advancednewsletter>
                <rewrite>
                  <subscriber>Etek_AdvancedNewsletterCoupon_Model_Subscriber</subscriber>
                <rewrite>
            </advancednewsletter>
          </models>
       </global>
```

__the subscriber model: Etek/AdvancedNewsletterCoupon/Mode/Subscriber.php

```
class Etek_AdvancedNewsletterCoupon_Model_Subscriber extends AW_Advancednewsletter_Model_Subscriber
  {
    _construct() {
        var_dump('Etek Subscriber');die(get_class($this));
    }
    public function subscribe($email, $segments, $params = array())
    {  echo"<pre>";die('Etek Subscriber');
  }
```

___Etek_AdvancedNewsletterCoupon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Etek_AdvancedNewsletterCoupon>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
              <AW_Advancednewsletter/>
            </depends>
        </Etek_AdvancedNewsletterCoupon>
    </modules>
 </config>
```

**Let me know if anyone has a solution.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was missing to close the rewrite tag now all works fine.

```
<rewrite>
 <subscriber>Etek_AdvancedNewsletterCoupon_Model_Subscriber<subscriber>
</rewrite>
```